# how to loop through List<WebElement>

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, gettext

I need help in getting the xpath for `List<WebElement>` and how to loop through it and select the link text which is equals to "2014 Benefits" from the below code.

```
<tbody id="tblPriorEventsBody">

<tr>
    <td>01/01/2014</td>
    <td>
        <a class="openEvent aActive" onclick='DisplayEventYearElections("dvCurrentElections","2014","Benefits For 01/01/2014 Open Enrollment ( 2014 ) ","2e82be0c-f280-4502-9d98-cf995450442c");' href="#">
            2014 Benefits
        </a>
        <input id="hfOpenEventDefinationId" type="hidden" value="b991cf84-f197-413f-a3fb-21c5a1c0d70a"></input>
    </td>
    <td>N/A</td>
    <td>N/A</td>
</tr>

<tr>...</tr> // Each tr contains a link
<tr>...</tr>
<tr>...</tr>
<tr>...</tr>
<tr>...</tr>

</tbody>
```

I am trying with the below code:

```
List <WebElement> options = Driver.findElements(By.xpath("//tbody[@id='tblOpenEventsBody']//tr/a"));

System.out.println(" CLASS  Elements size " + options.size());

for (WebElement option : options) {

String Str = "2014 Benefits" // based on string text match I want to select

if("Str".equals(option.getText())){
    option.click();  
   break();
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do something like...

```
List<WebElement> links = driver.find elements(By.cssSelector('#tblPriorEventsBody td a'));

Iterator<WebElement> iter = links.iterator();

while(iter.hasNext()) {
    WebElement we = iter.next();

    if (we.text.equals("whatever") {
        we.click;
    // do something in else perhaps
    }
}
```

Comment: If the above code works for you, please ensure that you click on accept answer.

Answer (score 3):

Finding the link *by link text* would be more reliable, readable and explicit:

```
WebElement element = Driver.findElement(By.linkText("2014 Benefits"));
```

Comment: I need to get List(WebElement> array of all links in <tbody>, each tr (inside td) contains a link, once I have this list now loop through list and compare the String text and select accordingly

Comment: @venkatkamraj sounds like an overhead for a task you are describing. Why don't get the link directly by link text? Am I missing smth? Thanks.

Comment: My requirement is to select the text which I pass from code in a string. For that I need to loop through all link texts then select if it matches.