# how to handle dynamic rows in selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I  have 4 dynamic rows (val_01062) and each contains 1 button (circle one) as shown in picture. i have to click on the button  on all of the dynamic rows. How to handle in selenium?
[image]

Comment: You'd better provide with `HTML` code for the same... Also share code you've tried with description of issues you've faced with your code

Comment: html will be too long.. i want the logic

Comment: OK. Use `click()` in a loop... Your question is too wide. You should share more specific details and show **what have you done already** to solve your problem

Comment: lol.. i want technical logic based answer exactly how to replicate.. click is not the answer

Comment: Refer [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26498299/how-to-loop-through-listwebelement) .You have to loop through rows and click on button.

Comment: even all buttons are dynamic

Comment: @Pope, This was the only good answer for this kind of question... To get better answer you should make a really good question. For now it seem that you just ask someone to write code for you... SO is not a code writing service

Comment: @ andersson i think you are unable to understand anything, i have strictly mentioned below your comment i want the technical logic not the code. i want something similar like peter pawar ..

Comment: @Pope you aren't understanding. The answer is to scrape the buttons off the page and loop through them clicking each button in the loop as Andersson said. If you want a more detailed answer, you need to provide a link to the page or some of the relevant HTML. What code have you written and what was the result including error messages? As others have said, SO is not a code writing service. You are supposed to provide your existing code so we can help you fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use xpath to find all buttons in your table and iterate over them to send a click. Correct your xpath based on your html code. If you have more buttons you need to add some filtering on id or class. You can easily test xpath in chrome to check if the correct elements are found.

```
List<WebElement> buttons = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table//button"));
for( WebElement button : buttons ) {
  button.click();
}
```

Comment: Thanks.let me try

Comment: hi i tired its woking partially. only 1st button is getting clicked. rest all button getting skipped and test is passing. how to deal

Comment: List<WebElement> buttons = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//img[(@src='/pilon/images/overide.gif')]"));
for( WebElement button : buttons ) {
  button.click();
}

Comment: Tested with a simple website where I searched for all spans in a table with a certain class and works as expected. Did you check the size of the buttons List if its contains enough elements? Does the click on a element changes the website like a refresh or something which causes "element is not attached to the page document"?  Or does it open a Modal which you first need to close via selenium to go back to the table?

Comment: button.size() is printing 4 button.  but not clicking 4 button

Comment: Please don't answer incomplete questions, it sets a bad precedent. This answer is too generic to be useful to others.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use a Map as explained in this article - http://www.testautomationguru.com/selenium-webdriver-finding-webelements-using-map/

You could access this by using - the way you want to access

`map.get(1).get("Override").click()`

or

`map.get("Val_01018").get("Override").click()`