# Is it possible to travel to next element by tag-name as we do in case of x-path?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

For above HTML =
first four elements I need to select NO

```
for(int a = 1;a<=4;a++){
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@value='False'])["+a+"]")).click();
    sleep(200);
}
```

which I'm doing simply by x-path.

Can I implement similar thing

```
driver.findElement(By.tagName("(textarea)[5]")).sendKeys("Yes input text");
```

I'm getting element not found error.
Is there any way to travel to **N**th element like x-path`(//input[@value='False'])[1/2/3/4]`

```html
<td colspan="2" xpath="1">
 <textarea style="width: 460px;" name="Note 0 86077d63-9f1c-43a6-b8cb-5f8cf833c963" id="Note 0 86077d63-9f1c-43a6-b8cb-5f8cf833c963" data-value="False" class="form-control" data-msg-required="Mandatory" required="required"></textarea>
</td>
```

```html
<textarea style="width: 460px;" name="Note 0 c942013d-e151-40aa-be33-4d16d28a5ca8" id="Note 0 c942013d-e151-40aa-be33-4d16d28a5ca8" data-value="False" class="form-control" data-msg-required="Mandatory" required="required" xpath="1"></textarea>
```

[This is my HTML code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6SQU.png)

Answer (score 0):

Do the `id` and `name` attributes change when refreshing the page?. If not you can try;

```
driver.findElement(By.id("Note 0 86077d63-9f1c-43a6-b8cb-5f8cf833c963")).sendKeys("Text you want to send");
```

Or

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//textarea[@name='Note 0 86077d63-9f1c-43a6-b8cb-5f8cf833c963']")).sendKeys("Text you want to send");
```

Comment: That is working.
I just want to know is any method for tag-name as well
`driver.findElement(By.tagName("(textarea)[1 or 2 or 3]"))`.
like this x-path
`driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//label[contains(text(),'Yes')])[5]"))`

Comment: Without the complete page HTML structure(at least the HTML component of text-area web elements), its hard to say whether a locator like `(textarea)[1 or 2 or 3]` will work. I understand you want to iterate through a set of web elements. There are other ways to do it, where you don't need to increment a number within the locator. Check the accepted answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26498299/how-to-loop-through-listwebelement)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `findElements` like this:

```java
driver.findElements(By.tagName("textarea")).get(4);
```

**P.S.** - List elements are accessed starting from index `0` so that the fifth element would have index `4`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
List<WebElement> textareaElements = driver.findElements(By.tagName("textarea"));
for(WebElement  ele: textareaElements ){
ele.click();
}
```